# Unsure how to nest / fold this power tower factorisation

Tags: function-construction

Not quite sure how to nest this. What I would like is power tower of integer factored until all powers are primes. eg desired output for `f[3*125^4]` would be `3*HoldForm[5^(3*HoldForm[2^2])]` or similar:

```
Times @@ Flatten[HoldForm[Power[##]] & @@@ (If[#[[2]] == 1, #[[1]], 
   If[PrimeQ[#[[2]]] == True, #, {#[[1]], 
     Times @@ Flatten[HoldForm[Power[##]] & @@@ (If[#[[2]] == 1, #[[1]], 
        If[PrimeQ[#[[2]]] == True, #]] & /@ 
          FactorInteger[#[[2]]])]}]] & /@ 
 FactorInteger[(3*125^4)])]
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Seems to generate the correct output

Comment: @yohbs want to generalize it for any input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I revised my previous function. Now it works great

```
nestFactor[n_Integer] := Block[{q, f},
  f = # /. {a_Integer, b_Integer} /; b > 1 :> {a,FactorInteger[b]} &;
  q = FixedPoint[f, FactorInteger[n]];
  Replace[q, {a_Integer, b_} -> HoldForm[a^b], -1] /. 
    HoldForm[a_^1] -> a //. {a_} -> a //. 
    List[a__] -> HoldForm[Times[a]]]
```

I verified that `(ReleaseHold//@nestFactor[n])/n` gives `1` for all the arguments I checked. Example:

[image]

Comment: seems to work nicely - thanks :) - Will continue to test :)

Comment: seems to work nicely up to about level 5: `nestFactor[3^56^4*5^48^4]`  then `nestFactor[Overflow[]]` with `nestFactor[3^56^9*5^48^4]`. That's a pretty large number though! Is there any way to overcome this with `Superscript` instead of `Power`? IOf nt, don't worry - quite happy with your function as is :)

Comment: Nice revision! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

This may be more of a long comment than an answer. You say that you want to generalize your code, but your code seems to work pretty generally already. You could just wrap it in a function, and use it as is:

```
powertower[n_Integer] := 
 Times @@ Flatten[
   HoldForm[
      Power[##]] & @@@ (If[#[[2]] == 1, #[[1]], 
        If[PrimeQ[#[[2]]] == True, #, {#[[1]], 
          Times @@ 
           Flatten[
            HoldForm[
               Power[##]] & @@@ (If[#[[2]] == 1, #[[1]], 
                 If[PrimeQ[#[[2]]] == True, #]] & /@ 
               FactorInteger[#[[2]]])]}]] & /@ FactorInteger[n])]
```

Your function seems to do what you want, i.e. factorize exponents as well until all factors are prime. For instance:

```
powertower[5^4*100^2*125^4*18^2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I suppose that the problem is that you would like the first factor in the example above to be $2^{3 2}$, rather than $2^6$. Please advise if I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: works only up to second level - try `powertower[3^56*5^48]`. Should evaluate to `3^(HoldForm[2^3]*7)*HoldForm[5^(3*HoldForm[2^(2^2)])]`.